# How to use Projection in LINQ to convert entity to DTO class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have Linq script and I want to use projection class to get data to DTO type. I got the example for lambda expersion but getting error on the LINQ script.

Linq Script:

```
public class EziTransactionDto
{
   ... other properties

 public static Expression<Func<EziTransactionEntity, EziTransactionDto>> Projection()
    {
        return eziTransactionDto => new EziTransactionDto
        {
            EziTransactionId = eziTransactionDto.Id,
            LoginSiteID = eziTransactionDto.LoginSiteID,
            WorkCodes = eziTransactionDto.WorkCodes
        };

    }
```

Linq query:

```
  var ts = (from transaction in _eziTransactionRepository.GetAll<EziTransactionEntity>()
                  where transaction.LoginErrorCode != 0
                  select transaction
                 ).Select(EziTransactionDto.Projection);
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Projection is a method ... use it as method not like a field

Comment: why negative if cannot answer it.. is not valid question ..

Comment: `Select(EziTransactionDto.Projection)` => `Select(EziTransactionDto.Projection())` ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess the keyword `Expression` is odd there.

Try this:

```
// public static Expression<Func<EziTransactionEntity, EziTransactionDto>> Projection()
public static Func<EziTransactionEntity, EziTransactionDto> Projection()
{
    return eziTransactionDto => new EziTransactionDto
    {
        EziTransactionId = eziTransactionDto.Id,
        LoginSiteID = eziTransactionDto.LoginSiteID,
        WorkCodes = eziTransactionDto.WorkCodes
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first Select your IQueryable has already fetched the data to the local process, and made it an IEnumerable.

You could do this conversion in your Select statement:

```
var eziTransactionDtos = _eziTransactionRepository.EziTransactionEntities
    .Where(eziTransactionEntity => eziTransationEntity.LoginErrorCode != 0)
    .Select(eziTransactionEntity => new EziTransactionDto
    {
        EziTransactionId = eziTransactionDto.Id,
        LoginSiteID = eziTransactionDto.LoginSiteID,
        WorkCodes = eziTransactionDto.WorkCodes,
    });
```

However, if you need to convert EziTransactionEntities to EziTransactionDtos on several places, it is a good idea to create a reusable extension method for `IQueryable<EziTransactionEntities>`.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IQueryable<EziTransactionDto> ToEziTransactionDto(
    this IQueryable<EziTransactionEntity> eziTransactionEntities)
{
    return eziTransactionEntities.Select(eziTransactionEntity => new EziTransactionDto
    {
        EziTransactionId = eziTransactionDto.Id,
        LoginSiteID = eziTransactionDto.LoginSiteID,
        WorkCodes = eziTransactionDto.WorkCodes,
    });
```

Usage:

```
var eziTransactionDtos = eziTransactionRepository.EziTransactionEntities
    .Where(eziTransactionEntity => eziTransationEntity.LoginErrorCode != 0)
    .ToEziTransactionDtos();
```

Reusable:

```
var transactionWithoutWorkCodes = eziTransactionRepository.EziTransactionEntities
    .Where(eziTransactionEntity => eziTransationEntity.WorkCode == null)
    .ToEziTransactionDtos();
```

Easy to unit test:

```
List<EziTransactionEntity> testItems = ...
List<EziTransactionDto> expectedResults = ...

var testResults = testItems.AsQueryable().ToEziTransactionDtos();
Assert.AreQual(expectedResults, testResults, unorderedTransactionsComparer);
```

Easy to maintain: if you add / remove / change one property of this conversion, you'll only have to do this on one location

Answer (score 0):

fond the answer

```
public static Expression<Func<EziTransactionEntity, EziTransactionDto>> Projection
    {
        get
        {
            return eziTransactionDto => new EziTransactionDto
            {
                EziTransactionId = eziTransactionDto.Id,
                LoginSiteID = eziTransactionDto.LoginSiteID,
                WorkCodes = eziTransactionDto.WorkCodes
            };
        }
    }
```

..

```
 var ts = (from transaction in _eziTransactionRepository.GetAll<EziTransactionEntity>()
                  select transaction
                 ).Select(EziTransactionDto.Projection).ToList();
```